# Edit joomla registration admin email

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, email-validation, user-registration

I want to change the email the admin gets when when a new user is being registered.
I want to add field he gets about the user.
I tried changing the `en-GB.com_user` file 
(although eventually I need it in Russian, but that's besides the point)
It didn't help.

When I tried a language override, I couldn't register new users at all.
I'm still guessing I can do it through language override by adding the right text
I just don't have a clue of what to write instead of : `%s \n E-mail: %s \n`

what does the `\n %s \n` mean?

I guess that somehow I need to change the `COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACTIVATE_WITH_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY`

but HOW and WHERE?

Comment: `\n` is the code for new line. `%s` is a string. The string could be anything depending on what the programmer intended, but in this case it is the e-mail address.

Comment: how do I choose what string do I put there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.

1. Find /home/joomla/public_html/components/com_users/models/registration.php
   and add:

   $emailBody = JText::sprintf(
   'COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACTIVATE_WITH_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY',
   $data['sitename'],
   $data['name'],
   $data['email'],
   $data['username'],
   $data['yourdatabasecolumn'],
   $data['siteurl'].'index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token='.$data['activation']
   );
2. Find /home/joomla/public_html/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini
   and add:

   COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACTIVATE_WITH_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY="Hello administrator,\n\nA new user has registered at %s.\nThe user has verified his email, and requests that you approve his account.\nThis email contains their details:\n\n Name : %s \n Email: %s \n Username: %s \n Yourdatabasename : %s \nYou can activate the user by clicking on the link below:\n %s \n"

everything must be in the right order